# sending http requests to docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, port

- I can send http requests from *within* a docker image, and get the expected responses.

```bash
$ docker build --tag host --file Dockerfile .
$ docker run -d -t --name flasky host 
$ docker exec -it flasky bash
root@da0da0d83330:/# flask run &
[1] 13
root@da0da0d83330:/#  * Serving Flask app 'main.py'
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/is_prime?number=19'
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2023 09:56:17] "GET /is_prime?number=19 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
19 is prime # <--- good ! that's correct !
```

- If I exit the docker, and get back in, server is still listening:

```
root@da0da0d83330:/# exit
exit
$ docker exec -it flasky bash
root@da0da0d83330:/# curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/is_prime?number=21'
21 is not prime # <--- good !
```

- When I send the *same* request from my host, I don't get *anything* back

```
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/is_prime?number=17'
# no response received, no errors received neither
```

- **EDIT** another attempt based on comment from [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)

```
$ cat compose.yml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container aaa-web-1  Created                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
Attaching to aaa-web-1
aaa-web-1  |  * Serving Flask app 'main.py'
aaa-web-1  |  * Debug mode: off
aaa-web-1  | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
aaa-web-1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
aaa-web-1  | Press CTRL+C to quit
```

- When I send the curl request, this time I *do* get an error:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8000/is_prime?number=30'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

- The `Dockerfile` for completeness:

```
FROM python:3.12
RUN pip install flask
COPY main.py main.py
ENV FLASK_APP=main.py
EXPOSE 5000
```

- The python code for completeness:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

def prime(p: int) -> bool:
    for i in range(2, p):
        for j in range(2,p):
            if i*j == p:
                return False;
    return True;

@app.route('/is_prime')
def hello_world():
    p: int = request.args.get('number')
    if p is not None:
        p_is_prime: bool = prime(int(p))
        if p_is_prime:
            return f'{p} is prime\n'
        else:
            return f'{p} is not prime\n'
    return 'missing input number'
```

Comment: Great - it's working as expected. What seems to be an issue? If you want to forward a port from a host to docker container, what documentation did you check?

Comment: @KamilCuk I took https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ and made it as minimal as I can - but it's not working

Comment: Great. How did you follow step 3? The `ports:
      - "8000:5000"` is important for docker redirection. See `docker --help` the `--port` option. Research port redirection in docker.

Comment: Ohhh I see - I somehow thought that exposing the port inside `Dockerfile` is enough (but I guess it isn't ?)

Comment: Actually, even if add a `compose.yml` with the specified port forwarding, I still can't get through [[:sad panda:]]. I'll edit my question

Comment: @KamilCuk, I edited the question

Comment: You need to set `host='0.0.0.0'` when you start the Flask application, or else it's unreachable from outside its own container.  Don't forget to set the image's default `CMD` to run the Flask app: the server should start itself, and you should not need `docker exec` in routine use.